# Ejs cicle for in tag script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

```
 var startDate, endDate, dateRange = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < '<%= object[0].Noleggi.length %>'; i++){
        startDate = formatDate('<%= object[0].Noleggi[i].DataInizio %>'); 
        endDate = formatDate('<%= object[0].Noleggi[i].DataInizio %>');
            for (var d = new Date(startDate);
                d <= new Date(endDate);
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
                    dateRange.push($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d));
            }
    }
```

this code in tag script in .ejs file, return in console
"i is not defined" I don't know wh

Comment: Are you sure? it returns "Noleggi is not defined"

Comment: The EJS JavaScript is a program which generates some HTML with a **different** program (also written in JavaScript) embedded in it. Those are two different programs, probably running on two different computers, and cannot share variables.

Comment: @masoud now I correct the code but the error it's the same